# Refreshing TextView in setOnClickListener

Tags: android, refresh, textview, onclicklistener

I have a `TextView` and a `button` i implemented a `setOnClickListener` method. I want to click on the button and update the `TextView`, unfortunately It just happens in the first click.
As you can see i used `view.invalidate();` to refresh the view, but not working.
Here is the code:

```
public class createtarget extends Activity {

    Button   mButton;

    TextView Board;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.createtarget);

       mButton   = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
       Board     =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.board);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) {
       String s=GiveText();   // Giving a String based on some computations
       Board.setText(s);
       view.invalidate();   //refreshing View
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First ,the view you are invalidating is actually the button itself and not the textview.
Second, is your textview's visibility INVISIBLE or GONE in the first run?
Third, what's actually your "Tsubtarget"?

Thanks.

Comment: 1-forget about _Tsubtarget_ i left it mistakenly
2-The TextView is Visible
3-How can i invalidate _Textview_? Could u describe it a little more?

Comment: @Josh To show the new String in the TextView? Am i doing  wrong?

Comment: Yes you are right. What should i do? The new Text never appears in the TextView

Comment: No need to invalidate the textview because whenever you call setText on it, it automatically is invalidated. Check the implementation of your "GiveText" method, it might be returning the same text.